# Login my Linux with root ,executing command sshd、tcpdump failed

Tags: linux, ssh, tcpdump

```
    root# /usr/sbin/sshd
    Privilege separation user sshd does not exist

    root# tcpdump -i eth0 udp  
    tcpdump : Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'
```

but the users tcpdump and sshd are in the files /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd

```
   root # cat /etc/passwd
   root:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
   bin:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
   daemon:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
   ftp:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
   oprofile:16:16:Special user account to be used by OProfile:/home/oprofile:/sbin/nologin
   tcpdump:72:72::/:/sbin/nologin
   sshd:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
   named:25:25:Named:/var/named:/sbin/nologin
   qmaild:505:504::/var/qmail:/bin/false
   qmaill:506:504::/var/qmail:/bin/false
   qmailp:x:507:504::/var/qmail:/bin/false
   qmailq:x:508:505::/var/qmail:/bin/false
   qmailr:x:509:505::/var/qmail:/bin/false
   qmails:x:510:505::/var/qmail:/bin/false
   apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
   mysql:x:27:27:MySQL Server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash
   dump:x:0:0::/tmp:/bin/dumpsh

   root # cat /etc/shadow
   root1$eigU8oI6$jYOcUeV1dunekVie/GWeL0:15264:0:99999:7:::
   dump1$mJQ/PAm7$t0JvrCVFDW2I/m2quQSd90:15391:0:99999:7:::
   bin:*:14789:0:99999:7:::
   daemon:*:14789:0:99999:7:::
   ftp:*:14789:0:99999:7:::
   oprofile:!!:14946::::::
   tcpdump:!!:14946::::::
   sshd:!!:14946::::::
   named:!!:122391:0:99999:7:::
   apache:!!:15191::::::
   mysql:!!:15191::::::
```

If there were someone know how to solve this problem,please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: use strace tcpdump -i eth0 udp like that you can see why you see that error

Comment: For sshd you may need to edit file /etc/ssh/sshd_config and "UsePrivilegeSeparation yes" to "UsePrivilegeSeparation no" OR Edit /etc/passwd and make the cnages as below 
sshd:x:74:74:privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin  and 
add this line into /etc/group
/etc/group:sshd:*::74:
Same you can do it for tcpdump. Hope this works for you

Comment: @c4f4t0r I have been seen the code of tcpdump,the reason why the error appears is code "pw = getpwnam(username)" return pw = NULL.The function getpwnam couldn't find 'usernme' in /etc/passwd.

Comment: It's never a good idea to post your passwords (even if hashed) publicly, btw.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's some text formatting weirdness but I thought I point it out:

```
sshd:74:74rivilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
```

should read

```
sshd:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
```

Not sure if this could cause problems like that but if it isn't a formatting error it is definitely worth looking at.